# How to clear a browser cached service worker when the old site is no longer accessible?

Tags: caching, dns, service-worker, browser-cache

I have built a new site for a customer and taken over managing their domain and using a new hosting. The previous site and hosting have been completely taken down.

I am running into a major issue that I am not sure how to fix. The previous developer used a service worker to cache and load the previous site. The problem is that users that had previous visited the site keep seeing the old one since it is all loading from a cache. This old site no longer even exists so I have no way of adding any javascript to remove the service worker from their browser unless they hit the new site.

Has anyone ever had this issue and know of a way to resolve it? Note, asking the users to delete the service worker from their browser won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cache busting to achieve the outcome. As per [Keycdn](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting)

> Cache busting solves the browser caching issue by using a unique file
>   version identifier to tell the browser that a new version of the file
>   is available. Therefore the browser doesn’t retrieve the old file from
>   cache but rather makes a request to the origin server for the new
>   file.

In case you want to update the service worker itself, you should know, for a service worker an update is triggered if any of the following happens:

- A navigation to an in-scope page.
- A functional events such as push and sync, unless there's been an update 
  check within the previous 24 hours.
- Calling .register() only if the service worker URL has changed. However, you should avoid changing the worker URL.

[Updating the service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates)

Comment: Thanks, but don't thing this solution will help. The whole site itself is run through the service worker so I am not able to perform any cache busting. I also do not have access to the service worker as this was setup and managed by a previous developer. Having the old developer do this is also not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the [`clear-site-data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data) header would be the most [thorough solution](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/#example-killswitch).